# How to solve module 'pyarrow.lib' has no attribute 'NAType' when importing ibis?

Tags: python, ibis

In python notebook, when im importing ibis its giving me the following error;

```
import ibis
```

Error;

```
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:219: RuntimeWarning: pyarrow._fs.FileSystem size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 48 from C header, got 56 from PyObject
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:219: RuntimeWarning: pyarrow.lib.Message size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 24 from C header, got 32 from PyObject
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:219: RuntimeWarning: pyarrow.lib.MemoryPool size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 32 from C header, got 40 from PyObject
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:219: RuntimeWarning: pyarrow.lib.DictionaryMemo size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 40 from C header, got 48 from PyObject
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:219: RuntimeWarning: pyarrow.lib._Metadata size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 16 from C header, got 24 from PyObject
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:219: RuntimeWarning: pyarrow.lib.KeyValueMetadata size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 48 from C header, got 56 from PyObject
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:219: RuntimeWarning: pyarrow.lib.Field size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 56 from C header, got 64 from PyObject
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:219: RuntimeWarning: pyarrow.lib.Schema size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 48 from C header, got 56 from PyObject
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:219: RuntimeWarning: pyarrow.lib.Scalar size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 24 from C header, got 48 from PyObject
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-a73c1a9e8fb0> in <module>
----> 1 import ibis

/home/esfnc/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ibis/__init__.py in <module>
     22 with suppress(ImportError):
     23     # pip install ibis-framework[parquet]
---> 24     from ibis.backends import parquet  # noqa: F401
     25 
     26 with suppress(ImportError):

/home/esfnc/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ibis/backends/parquet/__init__.py in <module>
      2 
      3 import pyarrow as pa
----> 4 import pyarrow.parquet as pq
      5 import regex as re
      6 from pkg_resources import parse_version

/home/esfnc/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyarrow/parquet.py in <module>
     36                               ColumnChunkMetaData,
     37                               ParquetSchema, ColumnSchema)
---> 38 from pyarrow.fs import (LocalFileSystem, FileSystem,
     39                         _resolve_filesystem_and_path, _ensure_filesystem)
     40 from pyarrow import filesystem as legacyfs

/home/esfnc/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyarrow/fs.py in <module>
     40 
     41 try:
---> 42     from pyarrow._hdfs import HadoopFileSystem  # noqa
     43 except ImportError:
     44     _not_imported.append("HadoopFileSystem")

/home/esfnc/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyarrow/lib.pxd in init pyarrow._hdfs()

AttributeError: module 'pyarrow.lib' has no attribute 'NAType'
```

I couldn't find the solution. How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a problem with your `pyarrow` installation.  Can you try a `conda install --force-reinstall pyarrow` and see if that fixes it?